# how to disable scroll wheel zoom in here maps javascript

Tags: javascript, here-api

we use javascript here maps and try to disable the scroll wheel zoom with `map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();`

this creats an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined**

is there an alternative?

here is the code from the map section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1542186754" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; background: grey" />
  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >


function addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, html) {
  var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);

  marker.setData(html);
  group.addObject(marker);
}


function addInfoBubble(map) {
  var group = new H.map.Group();

  map.addObject(group);

  group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {

    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {

      content: evt.target.getData()
    });

    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  }, false);

  addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:47.367800, lng:8.532460},
    '<div>Zürich' + '</div><div>Gartenstrasse 33<br>8002 Zürich</div>');

  addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:47.186080, lng:8.519480},
    '<div >Baar' + '</div><div>Grabenstrasse 5B<br>6340 Baar</div>');

  addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:47.166000, lng:9.555373},
    '<div>Liechtenstein' + '</div><div >Schliessa 16<br>9495 Triesen</div>');

}


var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'devportal-demo-20180625',
  app_code: '9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ',
  useHTTPS: true
});
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
});


var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat: 47.224350, lng:8.984120},
  zoom: 10,
  pixelRatio: pixelRatio
});

var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));


var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);


addInfoBubble(map);
            // Disable mousewheel zoom
            map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
  </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `disable` method on the *H.mapevents.Behavior* instance variable:

```
[...]
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior( new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map) )

// disable wheel zoom behavior
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM)
```

**Alternatively**, you can choose what behaviors to enable, when you instantiate the *H.mapevents.Behavior* object. To do that, use the optional second argument, like that:

```
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(
    new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map),
    {
        enabled: H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING | H.mapevents.Behavior.DBLTAPZOOM
    }
);
```